# WHERE clauses across SQL set operations

Tags: sql

Consider the following query, where both sets need to be filtered by the same `Location`. Is there a more efficient/performant approach whereby the `Location` filter is only applied once across both sets, or are you forced to apply the same filter to each set individually?

```
SELECT *
FROM   Orders
WHERE  Quantity BETWEEN 1 AND 100
AND Location = 'SE'

EXCEPT

SELECT *
FROM   Orders
WHERE  Quantity BETWEEN 50 AND 75
AND Location = 'SE';
```

**NOTE:** Not looking to refactor the set operations per se- it's just a dummy example. My question is only about how you would handle common WHERE clauses across set operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a [CTE](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/):

```
with ord (Column1, Column2) as
(
    SELECT Column1, Column2
    FROM Orders 
    WHERE Location = 'SE'
)
SELECT *
FROM ord
WHERE Quantity BETWEEN 1 AND 100

EXCEPT

SELECT *
FROM ord
WHERE Quantity BETWEEN 50 AND 75
```

If CTEs are not available, you could do the same thing with a view.

Comment: Not clear on the columns part- would this give me results side by side?

Comment: When using a CTE, you must explicitly name the columns rather than using `*`. That is what `Column1` and `Column2` represent here, since you provided no schema.

Comment: ahh- got it. OK, this may be what im after

Comment: Would the CTE approach be more performant, or is that irrelevant to how the query is structured?

Comment: CTEs typically improve performance when used to replace multiple similar queries, but not always. If performance is a concern, you need to test.

Answer (score 4):

I would re-factor the query to simply this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE Quantity BETWEEN 1 AND 100
AND Quantity NOT BETWEEN 50 AND 75
AND Location = 'SE';
```

Comment: No- i need separate set operations- i'm just interested in the common where filters (code was pasted from wikipedia set examples- i dont need a refactor of the actual sets)

Comment: @Yarin You'll do better to post the query you need help with, not one that incorrectly represents your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You may handle the set operations using AND NOT instead of EXCEPT [[1](http://bit.ly/QjN2F7)], with greater support across different platforms.

I think something worth mentioning, a summary:

1. Put least likely expression first.
2. Put least complex expression first.
3. Use greater and lesser searches.

Reverse point 1 & 2 if you use Oracle owing to right-to-left evaluation, instead of left-to-right.

Comment: @Yarin: Point 3 I'm referring to usage of comparison operators (e.g. >, <, ==) instead of logical operators (e.g. ANY, BETWEEN, EXIST). This is owing to comparison operation involve single index search but some logical operation involve multiple index search. An example (though may not be exact) can be found [here](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/36339/1954)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   Orders
WHERE  ((Quantity BETWEEN 1 AND 49) OR (Quantity BETWEEN 76 AND 100))
AND Location = 'SE'
```

Try this query and ensure it fetches the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Orders
WHERE  ((Quantity BETWEEN 1 AND 49)
OR (Quantity BETWEEN 76 AND 100))
AND Location = 'SE';
```

Comment: Now you are duplicating the answer @sundar already gave. Not sure there is much value in that.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Orders o1
WHERE  Quantity BETWEEN 1 AND 100 
AND Location = 'SE'
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM ORDERS o2 
                 WHERE QUANTITY BETWEEN 50 AND 75 
                 AND Location = 'SE' 
                 AND o1.ORDERS_ID = o2.ORDERS_ID)
```

Comment: From the question: *Is there a more efficient/performant approach whereby the Location filter **is only applied once** across both sets*